# How quantify the reading progress of large CSV files through pd.read_csv and chunks?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, chunks

### Analogy/Example

Let's say I have a list:

```
test_list = [2, 5, 3, 6]
number_of_elements = len(test_list)
```

Then `enumerate` can be used with `number_of_elements` to track the progress of a loop as follows:

```
for j, element in enumerate(test_list):
    do something
    print('completed {} out of {}'.format(j, number_of_elements))
```

### Question

Large csv files can be read as shown below ([reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas)):

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    process(chunk)
```

How to track the progress of this loop?

### Attempt

```
file_chunks = pd.read_csv(file_name, chunksize=100000)
number_of_chunks = len(file_chunks)
for j, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(file_name, chunksize=100000)):
    print(j, number_of_chunks)
```

Following is the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'TextFileReader' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it, the only problem is that there is no easy way for `len` to know how big the file is before reading it.

If you did:

```
file_chunks = pd.read_csv(file_name, chunksize=100000)

for i, chunk in enumerate(file_chunks):
    print(i)
```

That would work.

Also, this is a great use case for `Dask` (a python library that imitates a lot of pandas for big files)